# Ruby basic syntax and Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby

I am completely new to ruby.  I have the following code:

```
  body = "hello"
  site = "api.mysite.net"
  port = 80
  conn = Net::HTTP.new(site, port)
  resp, data = conn.post("/v1/profile", body, {})
  puts body
```

my questions are:

1. Where should I go for a library on how NET::HTTP.new() , conn.post() etc... works?
2. What does the comma between resp and data mean?
3. How come `puts body` gives me nothing even though I have hello defined initially?  And when passed through the post(), I figure it would assign it a value? but instead `puts resp.body` actually gives me the http response.

This is all so new to me, just trying to get a handle on things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) I guess, but you will need background knowledge on [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) to really understand it.
2. That's shorthand for assigning two variables at the same time, assuming the right-hand side returns an array of 2 (or more) items.
3. You've posted the body in your request, resp.body is the body in the response. I don't know why body should be empty though. I would double-check that, but it sounds like a side effect of `conn.post` if anything.

BTW there are several nice 3rd-party gems which make HTTP client development much easier than dealing with `Net::HTTP`, e.g. RESTClient, Excon, HTTparty. [Check these out](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients). Or if you want to use the standard Ruby library, also look at [Open URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) as a higher-level API.